# How to develop an elevation profile tool with high precision?

Tags: google-earth, topography, profile, cross-section

Similar to the Google Earth elevation profile tool, also similar to this:

http://www.geocontext.org/publ/2010/04/profiler/en/?send_comment=success#comments

I want to be able to use my own set of contours to generate the profile so it is highly accurate. I'm not sure whether it's easier to build from scratch or try to customize an existing application?

I also want to have the funcionality of the slider that shows the user the elevation when they mouse over the path.

From my understanding Google Earth uses SRTM data which has a +- 30m accuracy.... not good enough for my purposes. Any thoughts?

Comment: More details would be useful -- What area of the world,  What software you intend to use to do the contour-DEM conversion, What software you intend to use to serve of the data, ...

Comment: There are examples of this tool with some of the functionality on arcgis.com done in js and in flex. But I havent seen all the bells and whistles. The problem has been solid coverage at increasing resolution elevation data. If you have your own elev data you just need to decide platform, data type output and programming flavor. Narrow down those preferences and you should be able to find a direction.